# Initialize collections in a complex, immutable object

Tags: java, immutability

I have a complex object of class `MyClass` that my application will initialize many (thousands) of.  The application is multithreaded and these objects must be accessible from multiple threads.

Examples of some of the fields are:

```
final Map<String, Map<RelationSet, Set<String>>> packageRelationSetMap;
final Map<String, Set<String>> compiledUaAccessorySetMap;
```

To help avoid concurrency issues, I want to guarantee that instances of `MyClass` are immutable.

But, it is a pain to create every collection (or collection within a collection within a collection) and then wrap it in a `Collections.unmodifiableXXX()` every time.

I had a thought to make, using sets as an example, an inner class `MyClass.EventuallyImmutableSet implements Set`.  Basically it would work just like `java.util.Collections.UnmodifiableCollection` except that, (A) it wouldn't be `static` and (B) instead of automatically throwing `UnsupportedOperationException` in methods like `remove()`, it would first check a boolean variable in `MyClass` (say `immutabilityEnabled`).

My thought is that I could then modify the `MyClass` fields to be

```
final EventuallyImmutableMap<String, Map<RelationSet, EventuallyImmutableSet<String>>> packageRelationSetMap;
final EventuallyImmutableMap<String, EventuallyImmutableSet<String>> compiledUaAccessorySetMap;
```

Then I could build the collections as I am already doing during construction and just set `myClassInstance.immutabilityEnabled = true` at the end to guarantee immutability (assuming all the members of these collections are themselves immutable and all other requirements for immutability in general... I'm just asking about collections here).

Would this be a reasonable and effective approach to the problem?

#### Update (response to questions in comments)

> why the overly nested collections?

For example,

```
final Map<String, Map<RelationSet, Set<String>>> packageRelationSetMap;
```

The key in the outer map is a "package code", which has associated with it, a set of accessory codes.  As an aside, I do have a `Package` class that I could use in the `Map` in lieu its package code, but that still make the field definition:

```
final Map<Package, Map<RelationSet, Set<String>>> packageRelationSetMap;
```

... anyway, later on, in a performance-critical and heavily-used bit of code that jvisualvm profiling has revealed as a performance hog, I need to know, for each package, the `RelationSets` that it shares common accessories with and what that set of common accessories is.  (I am currently computing all that every time I need it and its taking too long).

I welcome refactoring suggestions as an alternative answer to the question.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why the overly nested collections? Sounds like a headache waiting to happen when you have to maintain over 2 years when it coughs up an error?

Comment: Indeed, the nesting of collections makes it appear like this one immutable object is a scary merge of like 3 different ones.

Comment: @Tschallacka I updated the question with an explanation.